# TypeError: this.props.sendKitchen is not a function ... why?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know this question is asked a lot  but I didn't found solution for me and I have no idea why i got this error.
The typeError is in my Order (child) component. And I use react and react-router.

This is my child component:

```
class Order extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.sendKitchen=this.sendKitchen.bind(this);
        this.state={
            name:'',
            choiceMenu:[],
            order:[],
            total:0,
            timeS:'',
            timeN:0
        }
    }
    sendKitchen(){

        let orderString=[];
        (this.state.order).forEach(food=>{orderString.push(food.name)});

        let date=new Date();
        let dateString=date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes();
        let dateNumber=date.getTime();

        let client={
            name:this.state.name,
            delivery: false,
            total: parseInt(this.state.total),
            timeS:dateString,
            timestamp:dateNumber,
            order: orderString
        };  
        this.props.toKitchen(client);
    }
    render(){
        return(

              <Button variant="success" onClick={this.sendKitchen}>ENVIAR A COCINA</Button>
        )}
```

And this is my Parent component

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toKitchen=this.toKitchen.bind(this);
    this.state={
      clients:[]
    }
  }
  toKitchen(client){
    console.log(client);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div >

        <Order
          sendKitchen={this.toKitchen}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried a lot of solution but still having the same error

EDIT: I delete the react-router part, I change the names of the functions that pass the props and still don't working. Also i change that functions to a arrow functions but the same error appear, so i remove that change.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess - it doesn't make any sens - too many options tried ;)

`<App/>` is usually rendered to html, not `<Router/>`

`<Router/>` should be inside `<App/>`

The one and only router case where `this.props.sendKitchen` make sense is `path='/' component={App}` - `<App/> renders``with`sendKitchen` prop. For '/order' this prop is undefined.

No redux here, remove tag.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't undestand, you say that the way that i use router it's wrong? And also i don't get it why sendKitchen it's wrong to send a prop

Comment: passing prop is not wrong at all but consuming this prop makes sense when it's defined - expecting it when not passed (wrong outer context) is wrong   - yes, overal app structure/usage is wrong

Comment: ok, i delete all the part of router from of my projects but still don't work  :(  so when you say the overal app structure is wrong, what part its wrong ?

Comment: button 'success' should work when app rendered to document node ... update code